# CSS background image align to center

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have background image on div size of image is 1920px x 850px.
and I have a some form, that always must be in a center of this div,
if user change size of screen or use less resolution, this form should be also always in center and background image should to center as well (left and right side of images is less important)
How to implement this behavior.
I also have some bootstap CSS on this page

```
.bg
{

    height: 850px;
    padding: 0px;
    zoom: 1;
    display: block;
    *display: inline;
    *float: none;
    background-image: url('full.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:white;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position:center top;
    width: 1920px;   
}

   <div class="row-fluid bg" id="formPart">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div class="span4 top200 subTitle">
                    @Html.Raw(T.Get("/LP/MainTitle"))
                </div>                  
                @using (Html.BeginForm("MyPage", Member",FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()                               
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    <div class="span4 top25 left30">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login)

                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 left30 inputSize">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 left30">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 left30 inputSize">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 left30">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 left30 inputSize">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)

                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 top15 bussines">
                        @Html.Raw(T.Get("/LP/SmallLinks"))
                    </div>

                    <div class="span4 top35">
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("error")
                        <a href="#" id="submitData">
                            <div class="span2 btnSun">
                                <div class="span2 top10 btnText">
                                    <div class="btnNewText play @Model.Culture.ToString()">@Html.Raw(T.Get("/LP/PlayButton"))</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>           
        </div>
```

Comment: in place of `<div class="col-lg-1"></div>' use  '<div class="col-lg-12"></div>'  it will work.

Comment: Please remove Razor from your HTMl, and make simple fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css-tricks.com have a lot trick for the CSS. This one hope it help your situation.

[Perfect full page background image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.bg
{
        height: 850px;
        padding: 0px;
        zoom: 1;
        display: block;
        *display: inline;
        *float: none;
        background-image: url('full.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-color:white;
        background-attachment: fixed;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Try adding

```
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

If for you height is more important change parameter backround-size to containt:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
 background-size: contain;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove width: 1920px; on .bg or add margin: auto;

However I do not understand the col-lg-1, if you want the block to be centered, do a .col-xs-12, or if smaller, for example 6 columns: .col-xs-6.col-xs-offset-3 (offset must be (12 - width) / 2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using "center-block" in the class or either style it in the css with the following:

```
#div {
    display: block; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```